# What isNoMethodError in ArticlesController#show ? and what is undefined method `category_id' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I am trying to display the article , that belongs to perticular category but i am getting undefined method 'category_id' for nil:NilClass error when i click on article in category show page....What to be done? someone help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3HLW.png)

Answer (score 1):

When object is nil and if you are trying to access value of nil object that time it throw an undefined_method error.

Here @article object is nil that's why it throwing an error.

```
@article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:id])
@category = Category.find_by_id(@article.category_id) if @article
```

You are using slug instead of id on resource routes

```
/articles/:slug
```

instead of

```
/articles/:id
```

change your route

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :articles, param: :slug
```

In terminal check your route is correct

```
 $ rails routes | grep article
...
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
```

instead of id it should slug

```
$ rails routes | grep article
...
article GET    /articles/:slug(.:format)      articles#show
```